# Textbook recommendations for weak topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, banach-spaces, book-recommendation, weak-topology

This is not a question regarding a specific mathematics problem, rather I am looking for some good texts that go into detail on the weak topology. My exposure to weak topologies is via Banach spaces but I would like to find a textbook that deals with weak topologies for general topological spaces as well as Banach spaces. Does anyone know of such textbooks? I already have a copy of Brezis as well as Rudin's functional analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Books on linear topological spaces are probably what you're looking for.  In a sense, a LTS (or a TVS, topological vector space) is what underlies a Banach space as that requires completeness which is not always available.

Two I can definitely recommend are:

[Linear Topological Spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-41914-4) by Kelley and Namioka (et al) -- it's a SpringerVerlag book and the link is to the Springer website; you may find copies in a library, or cheaper elsewhere.

[Topological Vector spaces and their applications](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319571164) by Bogachev and Smolyanov -- also SpringerVerlag and that link includes a free preview of the book.

Of the two, I prefer Bogachev which has a very clean, analytical style and is more recently written.  Both books are comprehensive, and both cover substantially more than just the weak topology.